# How to create additional thumbnails of custom size in nextgen gallery while uploading images?

Tags: plugin-nextgen-gallery

Is there any way out to create additional thumbnails of custom size in nextgen gallery while uploading images?
For example I would like to create 3 thumbnails of size 25*30, 100*50, and 400*350 to display them in certain custom pages.Or can i add custom code to resize when image upload is triggered and if so where?

Answer (score 0):

Make shure your theme function have

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

to add a custom image size use

```
add_image_size( 'thumb-one', 25, 30 );
```

for more details have a looh [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)

Comment: but how will this thumbnail get generated while uploading while nextgen gallery ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a custom function to re-size the thumbnails you need to have a look at `gd.thumbnail.inc.php` in the lib folder of the plugin. This is where the thumbnails are generated.

Alternatively you can create custom a template for displaying different thumbnail sizes.

If you have a look in the view folder anyone of those files will give you a clue as to how to create a template for the plugin.

Once you create a template you can display it with a shortcode like `[ nggallery id=X template=your_template ]`